# Django: Set kwargs value for excluded field in generic view

Tags: django, django-generic-views, keyword-argument, create-view

Hi I am trying since yesterday.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('events:event-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Kategorie(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport)
    ....
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^kategorie/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/create/$', views.KategorieCreate.as_view(), name='kategorie-create'),
```

**html**

```
<a href="{% url 'events:kategorie-create' event.id %}">Neue Kategorie</a>
```

**views.py**

```
class KategorieCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Kategorie
    fields = ['sport',...]       # 'event' is excluded
    template_name_suffix  = '_create_form'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(KategorieCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['event'] = kwargs.get(self.pk)
        return context
```

I received:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: events_kategorie.event_id

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback ?

Comment: Already works with Roseman's response. Tried to set the foreignkey value 'event' via <pk> to the KategorieForm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point setting that value in the context; you need to do so in the form instance. This is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.event_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    return super(KategorieCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Note, I can't actually understand what value you are trying to insert there. It makes no sense to use a category PK as the id of the event.

Comment: I tried so many form_valid, get_response, __init__, save, ... Always had no value or empty kwargs. I think I had "form.event = self.kwargs.get('pk'). I want to set the event, which I excluded from the fields. I updated my question so it get's clearer, hopefully.

Comment: That didn't really help. What didn't work in my answer?